# Large ethernet frames (beyond jumbo)?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, ethernet

I am analyzing a log I captured with WireShark and I was surprised to find that one of the applications we use in-house that only talks to another host (both connected to a private, internal hub) sends/receives huge frames (on the order of 15K). I thought the max was 9K for jumbo frames. How can one generate these frames? The app uses tcp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The app uses tcp.

...and the Ethernet adapter might be doing [Large Segment Offload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_segment_offload) or [Large Receive Offload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_receive_offload), in which case the packets that the capture mechanism used by libpcap/WinPcap (which tcpdump/WinDump, Wireshark, etc. use to capture traffic) provides to the library and application might be "fake" packets corresponding to more than one packet "on the wire".